# If $~\lim_{x\to a}(f(x))^4 = 0~$, prove that $~\lim_{x\to a} \bigl(−2f(x)\bigr) = 0~$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $~a ∈ \mathbb R~$ and let $~f: \mathbb R → \mathbb R~$. If $~\lim_{x\to a}(f(x))^4 = 0~$ then provide a complete $~δ − ε~$ proof that $~\lim_{x\to a} \bigl(−2f(x)\bigr) = 0~$.

Can somebody help me with this one? I'm struggling to even start the proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In this problem $\lim\limits_{x\to ????????} f(x)^4 =0$.  What is $????????$?  That actually has to be specified.

Answer (score 2):

Let$\epsilon>0$.

Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $|x-a|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)|^4<\epsilon$.

If we consider $\delta>0$ and we choose $|x-a|<\delta$ then

$|f(x)|^4<\epsilon$

that means

$|f(x)|<\epsilon^\frac{1}{4}$

So

$|-2f(x)|<2 \epsilon^\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given, and put $\epsilon':=\bigl(\epsilon/2\bigr)^4>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to a}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)^4=0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$0<|x-a|<\delta\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad\bigl|(f(x))^4-0\bigr|<\epsilon'\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad  \bigl|f(x)\bigr|^4<\bigl(\epsilon/2\bigr)^4\ .$$
We therefore have
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad|f(x)|\leq{\epsilon\over2} \qquad \Rightarrow\qquad |-2f(x)|<\epsilon\ .$$
As $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary this proves $\lim_{x\to a}\bigl(-2f(x)\bigr)=0\ .$